# How to give text to UILabel dynamically from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to create collection view in iOS application where an image and label will be displayed. I am able to display the images in Collection view, but am facing problem with `UILabel`. I have:
`NSArray *categoryArray;` 
`categoryArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc",@"xyz",@"qwe",@"asdf",@"fgh",@"hjk",@"lkj",@"ghj",@"sdf",nil];`.

Now I want this text to be assigned dynamically to the `UILabel` which is placed in Collection view.
Here's what I have tried.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];
    //UILabel *txtCatName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
//    txtCatName.text = @"Testing";
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this after the line
 `cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];`

```
/*This is to avoid overlapp due to cell reuse.This will remove all labels in the cell. If only a particular label is to be removed put a tag range to it like label.tag = 100+indexPath.row and change the if accordingly to match this tag range*/

for (UIView *view in cell.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}


UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];//Set the frame as per your requirement.
[label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
[cell addSubview:label];
return cell;
```

Also if you are using custom cell, add a `UILabel` to the cell and create an `IBOulet` property and then update the text in this method. No need to worry about overlapping then. It would be better to add through xib since looping through all the subviews will cause performance problem if the number of subviews increase. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put the Label in the `UICollectionViewCell` and then in the same way as you have added the image, add the label text dynamically. Edit your function code to something like this.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];

    cell.txtLabel.text = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //UILabel *txtCatName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
//    txtCatName.text = @"Testing";
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Label Tag and try this. (set Label Tag:99)

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];
     UILabel *txtCatName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:99];
        txtCatName.text = [categoryArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] ";
    return cell;
}
```